# Is this a Appropriate method to safely close a proxy on WCF-calls?

Tags: wcf, generics, proxy

In my application i discovered that sometimes the Close() for a WCF-call/channels trowed errors.
And i did a little research on the subject and borrowed some code on the internet to get me started.

And now, I wonder is this the right way to go? or should i improve the solution or maybe implement something totally different?

Generic-Class/Static Class:

```
public class SafeProxy<Service> : IDisposable where Service : ICommunicationObject
{
    private readonly Service _proxy;
    public SafeProxy(Service s)
    {
        _proxy = s;
    }
    public Service Proxy
    {
        get { return _proxy; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_proxy != null)
            _proxy.SafeClose();
    }        
}

public static class Safeclose
{
    public static void SafeClose(this ICommunicationObject proxy)
    {
        try
        {
            proxy.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            proxy.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how i make calls to the WCF:

(The WCFReference is a Service Reference pointing to the WCF service adress)

```
using (var Client = new SafeProxy<WCFReference.ServiceClient>(new WCFReference.ServiceClient()))
{
    Client.Proxy.Operation(info);                        
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick little extension method I use to safely interact with a WCF service from the client:

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper class for WCF clients.
/// </summary>
internal static class WcfClientUtils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a method on the specified WCF client.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the WCF client.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TU">The return type of the method.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="client">The WCF client.</param>
    /// <param name="action">The method to execute.</param>
    /// <returns>A value from the executed method.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="CommunicationException">A WCF communication exception occurred.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="TimeoutException">A WCF timeout exception occurred.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="Exception">Another exception type occurred.</exception>
    public static TU Execute<T, TU>(this T client, Func<T, TU> action) where T : class, ICommunicationObject
    {
        if ((client == null) || (action == null))
        {
            return default(TU);
        }

        try
        {
            return action(client);
        }
        catch (CommunicationException)
        {
            client.Abort();
            throw;
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            client.Abort();
            throw;
        }
        catch
        {
            if (client.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                client.Abort();
            }

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (client.State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
                {
                    client.Close();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                client.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I call it as such:

```
var result = new WCFReference.ServiceClient().Execute(client => client.Operation(info));
```

Comment: I've implemented this, and it works perfectly. Very nifty to use